# Java - Swing Timer starts displaying a bit later than expected

Tags: java, swing, timer

I am making a game. I want to have something like a clock showing how much time has passed from the begging of the game. It works almost fine, but it starts maybe a second or two later than the actual game starts. I don't know what's the reason for this, so I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

I created a similar situation (runnable).

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javax.swing.Timer;


public class GUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private Timer SimpleTimer;

    public GUI() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(154, 154, 154)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(131, 131, 131)
                        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(196, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(92, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 23, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(48, 48, 48)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(137, 137, 137))
        );

        pack();
    }                      

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        startGame();
    }                                        

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new GUI().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;             

    private void startGame() {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if(SimpleTimer != null) {
            SimpleTimer.stop();
        }
        SimpleTimer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                jLabel1.setText("Time passed: " + String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis))));
            }
        });
        SimpleTimer.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: A time delay of `0`  here: `Timer(0, new ActionListener()...)` is not realistic and risky. This should be 13 to 15 at the lowest.

Comment: `"I think that this is all the code relevant to the timer..."` -- look at the [mcve] and then try to create and post one of these. If you make it easy as possible for us to understand your code and your problem, you're likely going to get better and quicker answers.

Comment: And this is wrong: `//I just needed to initialize it so that I can check if it is already running`. No. All you need to do is to first check for null, and then if not null, check if running.

Comment: Oh, thank you for that note :). I will try to recreate it as simple as possible and post back!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I added a new code it resembles my situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your time calculations look off. Shouldn't it be something like:

```
String text = String.format(TIME_FORMAT, 
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis) % 24,
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) % 60,
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) % 60);
timerLabel.setText("Time passed: " + text);
```

Edit: no, your conversions are OK. I do recommend that your Timer use a finer granularity then 1 second if you're displaying 1 second units. Here I use a granularity of 100 milliseconds.

Note that your code does not run for me (try copy and running your posted code to see what it does).

Please check out what an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should look like below, and then copy and run this code to see a timer that works:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SimpleTimer extends JPanel {
    private static final String TIME_FORMAT = "%02d:%02d:%02d";
    public static final int TIMER_DELAY = 100;
    private static final int PREF_W = 300;
    private static final int PREF_H = 100;
    private long startTime;
    private Timer myTimer;
    private JLabel timerLabel = new JLabel("00:00:00");
    private JCheckBox fastChkBox = new JCheckBox("Run Artificially Fast", false);

    public SimpleTimer() {
        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        centerPanel.add(new JButton(new RestartAction("Restart", KeyEvent.VK_R)));
        centerPanel.add(fastChkBox);

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.add(new JLabel("Time passed: "));
        topPanel.add(timerLabel);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private class RestartAction extends AbstractAction {
        public RestartAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
            super(name);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (myTimer != null && myTimer.isRunning()) {
                myTimer.stop();
            }

            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            myTimer = new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new TimerListener());
            myTimer.start();
        }
    }

    // make it bigger
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        Dimension superSz = super.getPreferredSize();
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return superSz;
        }
        int prefW = Math.max(superSz.width, PREF_W);
        int prefH = Math.max(superSz.height, PREF_H);
        return new Dimension(prefW, prefH);
    }


    private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;

            if (fastChkBox.isSelected()) {
                millis *= 512;  // make time go faster
            }
            String text = String.format(TIME_FORMAT, 
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis) % 24,
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) % 60,
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) % 60);
            timerLabel.setText(text);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        SimpleTimer mainPanel = new SimpleTimer();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleTimer");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

---

Edit: your code without the NetBeans builder junk:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private Timer SimpleTimer;

    public GUI() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel("   Time passed: 00:00:00   ");
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("Restart");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
        btnPanel.add(jButton1);
        JPanel labelPanel = new JPanel();
        labelPanel.add(jLabel1);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(labelPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        pack();
    }

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        startGame();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new GUI().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;

    private void startGame() {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (SimpleTimer != null) {
            SimpleTimer.stop();
        }
        SimpleTimer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                jLabel1.setText("Time passed: " + String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)
                                - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES
                                .toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis))));
            }
        });
        SimpleTimer.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: I copied it from another place, so I guess that it is the problem, but your version doesn't work for me either :(

Comment: Your code does not run for me. Please see edit to answer to see what I mean about a correct [mcve] and an example of restarting a timer. I've also included a check box to make the timer go artificially fast.

Comment: I runned it, it workerd for me, that's odd. I will see your example.

Comment: @vixenn: Edit: no, your conversions are OK. I do recommend that your Timer use a finer granularity then 1 second if you're displaying 1 second units. Here I use a granularity of 100 milliseconds.

Comment: Okay, I will try it. I posted new code(I was trying to avoid the auto generated code, but I can't make it work otherwise). Hope it runs now.

Comment: I had set the label to be "" initially. If I set it to "Time passed: 00:00:00" and making the granularity 100 ms looks pretty decent. Thank you for all the tips. Sorry if I wasted your time.

Comment: @vixenn: you're welcome, and in the future, there's no need for the NetBean's autogenerated code. Please see my edit to **your** code above, that gets rid of the netbeans junk.

Comment: Thank you very muuch! I am way too bad with GUI, so this helps clear things up and is wayyy simpler than NetBeans' autogenerated code!